# How to hook IDropTarget::Drop

Tags: windows

I am looking for the document how to hook IDropTarget::Drop function.
I'd like to add my dll into the target application as a plugin, and hook IDropTarget::Drop function to get the dropped files. Is there anyone who have already done the similar implementation?

Answer (score -1):

You would probably have to take over the registration in the registry so Windows will activate your custom application instead. You would then have to spawn the real application and manually connect to the real application after it has called `CoRegisterClassObject` and forward the drop to it. This is not beginner COM stuff and only deals with drops on the .exe and launches of its registered file types. To deal with drops on the applications window you would also gave to inject a .dll at the point where you call CreateProcess on the real application. You also have to consider the fact that the application might be using the old `WM_DROPFILES` instead.

This is very complicated and even if you could get all of it working, it would still not handle the case where the user starts the application from the start menu and then drops files on the window. To handle that scenario you would also have to register yourself as a debugger for it in the `Image File Execution Options` key so you can inject your .dll.

At this point we are far into "evil" territory. It is not acceptable to overtake other applications in this fashion.

Your only real option is to ask the original authors if they can add plug-in support to the application.